# Automator folder generation - strange problem

Tags: automator

Hoping someone here can shed some light on an issue I've been having with Automator. For work, we needed something to auto-generate folders & sub folders based on answering 2 questions. The first asks for "Job No", and the second asks for "Job name". Whatever the user answers sets 2 variables - one for Job No and the other for "Job name".

This works well. From here I have a shell script which then generates specific folder structures which inherit the Job No ( example - CF1005 ) , using a folder renaming action in Automator. This works quite well, except foe the subfolders.

The initial set of folders are renamed correctly. That is, they have the Job No added to them as a prefix. However it's the sub-folders that's causing the issue. Sometimes one of the subfolders is renamed correctly, other times it's a few folders. See below:

[Directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AS67f.jpg)

As you can see, the folders with XX_ as the prefix aren't bring renamed with the Job No. Please note, this isn't always the case. It's hit and miss. The only thing I can think of is timing. I suspect the renaming action is being executed while the folders & subfolders are still being created by the OS?? I'm stumped. I've added some pauses and that seems to give me a higher success rate, but it's not a 100% success rate. Here's a screengrab of my workflow:

[Automator Workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzFKA.jpg)

Can someone here shed some light on what the issue might be? Last note. At present we can't run this app within a box.com folder. It issues us with an error. Not sure if someone here can help with is, but I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the problem is the `Get Selected Finder Items` action, which I can't quite see the sense of. Instead, try it this way (beginning with the `Pause` action):

[image]

The `Find Finder Items` action gathers just the files you need and passes them straight into the rename action (after another short pause).

Comment: Thanks Ted. I'm new to automator, and I couldn't work out what the difference was between Find Finder Items, and Get Selected Finder Items. I'll give your solution a go and see what happens.

Comment: `Get Selected Finder Items` gets the values of the items that are actually selected in the frontmost Finder window. `Find Finder items` performs a spotlight search and returns the results. FYI...